# Code Map is slow

Tags: visual-studio, code-map

I'm working with VS 2013 Ultimate and using Code Map feature, but I have to wait minutes for commands like 'Show Containing Type' finish execution. How can I improve it's performance?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-maps-performance) has a few helpful tips.

The trick I found to be most helpful is selecting **Skip Build** in the Code Map window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS Enterprise 2017, and at times that the Code Map feature is painfully slow, such as when expanding the children of a particular assembly or while VS attempts to create indexes... I don't have formal data on this, but it seems that rebuilding the solution (i.e., cleaning then building) speeds-up a new code map request and the expansion of assemblies within the generated code map.